# What is the minimum structure required for a Java POJO to be marshalled as a JSON?

Tags: java, json, marshalling

This is quite straight forward. What is the minimum required structure for a Java POJO to be marshalled as a JSON?

Can you marshall an object as a JSON if it has only getters/setters or are the field declarations mandatory?

Setter/Getter example:

```
class Circle{
 private float radius;
 private float pi;

 // setter and getters for those aboce;

 public float getArea(){
 // returns the computed area;
 }
}
```

So can such an object be marshalled as a JSON if the "area" field is not defined in the Foo class as a field? Or is it mandatory to explicitly declare all fields in your POJO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

**Circle**

For MOXy the only annotation required would be `@XmlElement` on the `area` property as there is no setter corresponding to the getter.  The `@XmlElement` is included in Java SE 6 and above:

```
package forum10028037;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

class Circle{

    private float radius;
    private float pi;

    public float getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(float radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public float getPi() {
        return pi;
    }

    public void setPi(float pi) {
        this.pi = pi;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public float getArea(){
        return pi * radius * radius;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum10028037;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Circle.class);

        Circle circle = new Circle();
        circle.setPi(3.14f);
        circle.setRadius(10.1f);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
        marshaller.marshal(circle, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
{
   "area" : 320.31143,
   "pi" : 3.14,
   "radius" : 10.1
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/binding-to-json-xml-geocode-example.html

Comment: I guess this is more of what i was looking for. All answers are correct in a way but i found yours as the most complete. Thank you for the time taken to clarify this for me.

Comment: The answer provided by Mr. Doughan is quote correct. Let me add two more things. First, by removing just one line of code (setting application.media-type) you will get XML instead. The ease of switching between JSON and XML is one of the charms of MOXy. Second, marshalling and unmarshalling with MOXy is fast (well under a microsecond in some of my tests). Creating the JAXBContext is slow. Create the JAXBContext just once and keep it around.

Answer (score 1):

This would really depend on the marshalling engine.  Using jackson-mapper under Spring recently, if I didn't have getter operations (getArea() good example) then my instance could not be correctly marshalled.

Hypothetically speaking, if you have the standard bean set/get (or in your case get), it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library then getters/setters are not required:

Example from the [user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide):

```
class BagOfPrimitives {
  private int value1 = 1;
  private String value2 = "abc";
  private transient int value3 = 3;
  BagOfPrimitives() {
    // no-args constructor
  }
}

BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);  
==> json is {"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}
```